# JSON TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I'm trying to store an exception error to json. Even though I'm pretty sure I'm storing a string, it's still giving me a typeerror.

Relevant section of code:

```
except ConnectionError as e:
        s = str(e)
        print type(s)
        data = json.loads({'error message': s})
        print "JSON load succeeded"
```

Traceback:

```
<type 'str'>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[REDACTED]", line 36, in <module>
    ping(SERVERS)
  File "[REDACTED]", line 29, in ping
    data = json.loads({'error message': s})
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

This is quite baffling to me. I'd appreciate any help with this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `json.dumps()`, not `json.loads()`. Try this:

```
    data = json.dumps({'error message': s})
```

[`json.dumps(obj)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps): Serialize `obj` to a JSON formatted `str`
[`json.loads(s)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads): Deserialize s (a `str` instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object